# Android - How to detect change in compass degree (Java)

Tags: java, android, compass

I have the following code that perfectly works on my Nexus 5.

```java
public void onSensorChanged(SensorEvent event) {
        float degree = Math.round(event.values[0]);
        displayMsg.setText(String.valueOf(degree));
}
```

`degree` contains the compass's direction. What I want to do is to detect change in direction. So let's say if a person is walking north and then the turn 10 degrees to the right. As soon as the person changes direction, I want to be able to notice. Also, there are uncertainties. So for example when the person is walking North, the direction isn't constant 0 degrees. It will be fluctuating between 358 and 2-3 degrees.

I thought of using `Timer.schedule` to store the degrees every 500 ms and then do a

```java
if(Math.abs(degree - storedDegree) > 10)
   Toast.makeText(this,"Direction Changed",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
```

However this method runs out of memory due to the number of threads created I think.
Is there a smarter/better way of detecting change in direction?

---

**UPDATE**

Here's the full code I'm doing.

I am counting steps and I want to keep the direction that the steps are taken.  As soon as the direction is changed by say 10 degrees, the step counter should store the value it has (say in an array list) and then go to 0 and restart counting.

```
boolean start = true;

@Override
public void onSensorChanged(SensorEvent event) {
    //------------------------------Compass--------------------------------------
    final float degree = Math.round(event.values[0]);
    displayMsg.setText(String.valueOf(degree));
    //---------------------------------------------------------------------------

    Sensor sensor = event.sensor;
    float[] values = event.values;
    int value = -1;
    int steps;

    if (values.length > 0) {
        value = (int) values[0];
    }

    if(mode.equals("Start"))
    {
        if (sensor.getType() == Sensor.TYPE_STEP_COUNTER) 
        {
            if(start)
            {
                count = value;
                start = false;
            }
            steps = value-count;
            stepCounter.setText("Step Counter Detected : " + steps);
        } 
    }
}
```

Comment: What is wrong with what you have?  It seems like onSensorChanged should be called when ever the person changes direction, and then you just compare the current degree to a stored value (like you have shown)

Comment: `onSensorChanged` doesn't get called overtime the person changes direction. it constantly gets called always. The problem with what I proposed is that I use `Timer timer = new Timer();` then `timer.schedule(timerTask,5000)` method.  but this method runs out of memory!

Answer (score 1):

I would use a low pass filter, to eliminate the fluctuations.

here's the code:

```
protected float[] lowPass(float[] input, float[] output) {
    if (output == null) return input;
    for (int i = 0; i < input.length; i++) {
        output[i] = output[i] + ALPHA * (input[i] - output[i]);
    }
    return output;
}
```

Where ALPHA is 
static final float ALPHA = 0.25f;

I'll also post code for getting the "direction". Maybe it helps you:

```
protected void onResume() {
    super.onResume();
    mSensorManager.registerListener(this, accelerometer, SensorManager.SENSOR_DELAY_UI);
    mSensorManager.registerListener(this, magnetometer, SensorManager.SENSOR_DELAY_UI);
}

protected void onPause() {
    super.onPause();
    mSensorManager.unregisterListener(this);
}


@Override
public void onSensorChanged(SensorEvent event) {
    if (event.sensor.getType() == Sensor.TYPE_ACCELEROMETER)
        mGravity = lowPass(event.values.clone(), mGravity);
    if (event.sensor.getType() == Sensor.TYPE_MAGNETIC_FIELD)
        mGeomagnetic = lowPass(event.values.clone(), mGeomagnetic);
    if (mGravity != null && mGeomagnetic != null) {
        float R[] = new float[9];
        float I[] = new float[9];
        boolean success = SensorManager.getRotationMatrix(R, I, mGravity, mGeomagnetic);
        if (success) {
            float orientation[] = new float[3];
            SensorManager.getOrientation(R, orientation);
            azimut = orientation[0]; // orientation contains: azimut, pitch and roll
        }
    }

}
```

after this, use the azimut like this:

```
        if (azimut != null) {
            canvas.rotate(-azimut * 360 / (2 * 3.14159f), centerx, centery);

            if ((azimut > -0.2) && (azimut < 0.2)) current_direction = "North";
            if ((azimut > 1.3) && (azimut < 1.7)) current_direction = "East";
            if (((azimut < -2.8) && (azimut > -3.2)) || ((azimut < 3.2) && (azimut > 2.8))) current_direction = "South";
            if ((azimut > -1.7) && (azimut < -1.3)) current_direction = "West";
        }
```

Comment: Where would I exactly set my mGravity and mGeomagnetic?

Comment: And these codes are just different way of doing the compass. I want to detect whenever theres a 10 degree change in the direction

Answer (score 1):

I think your problem is more related to the sensors and not your logic. You can try this, but I am not really failure with the sensors.  I know the location service can provide you with a device bearing (via gps), which might also be an option.

Can you check that the current degree has changed by more than your threshold, and then update the stored value with the new degree?

one possible example would be something like this:
The idea is that since onSensorChanged is called whenever a value is updated, you can check if the difference between the current degree and a stored value is more than some threshold.
If it is take action and store the new degree, if not the change is simply ignored.

```
private float storedDegree;

public void onSensorChanged(SensorEvent event) {
    if (sensor.getType() == Sensor.TYPE_ORIENTATION) {
        float degree = Math.round(event.values[0]);
        if(Math.abs(degree - storedDegree) > 10) {
            Toast.makeText(this,"Direction Changed",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            displayMsg.setText(String.valueOf(degree));
            storedDegree = degree;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I think you need to show more of your code then, and explain what is happening